# Generar una función JavaScript para borrar determinado elemento con determinada clase

Tags: javascript

Mi motivo con este código es generar una variable la cual será utilizada en un `addEventListener` y que tendrá la función tanto de recorrer los elementos de una lista, como evaluar si tienen una clase y además, de cumplirse el heho de que tenga esa clase, ser borrado. El problema que me arroja es que el elemento `children` no está definido.

A continuación el código:

```
var eleminarTarea = function(){

    for (var k = 0; k <= List.children.length -1; k++){

        if(List.children[k].className === "ViewDelett0element")
        {
            //  En Otros Intentos Trate Con :
            // `List.childrenNodes[K].removeChild(child);`
            // `this.children.removeChild(child);`
            // `this.children.removeChild(this)`

            this.parentNode.addEvent(this.parentNode.removeChild(child));
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Hijole , gracias de Nuevo , crei haber usado la sintaxis correcta. )=

Comment: Emmanuel, en dónde definís `List`? Por otro lado, `eleminarTarea` (ojo que pusiste "el**E**minar") la estás pasando cuando llamás a `addeventListener`? Podrías mostrar las líneas con esto?

Comment: Y te anticipo que para eliminar un hijo, tenés que pararte en en padre: `var nodoEliminado = algunNodo.parentNode.removeChild(algunNodo)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partir de un elemento padre, para eliminar todos los hijos que pertenecen a una clase, es necesario pararse en el padre para poder usar **[.removeChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild)**.

```js
function eliminarElementosDeClase(elementoPadre, nombreDeClase) {
 //Obtener todos los hijos que coinciden con el nombre de la clase
    hijosDeEsaClase = elementoPadre.getElementsByClassName(nombreDeClase);
    
    //Loop para c/u
    var len = hijosDeEsaClase.length;
    for (var i = len-1; i >= 0; i--) {
     //Borrar 1 elemento (parándose en el padre)
        hijosDeEsaClase[i].parentNode.removeChild(hijosDeEsaClase[i]);
    }
}

// ----------
// EJEMPLO
var List = document.getElementById("contenedor");
eliminarElementosDeClase(List, "ViewDelett0element");
```

```html
<span id="contenedor">
    <span class="ViewDelett0element">Borrame</span>
    <span class="dejame">No me peguen</span>
    <span class="ViewDelett0element">Borrame</span>
    <span class="dejame">soy Giordano</span>
 </span>
```

---

O, si usás jQuery

```
$('#contenedor').find('.ViewDelett0element').remove();
```

Comment: SI , disculpa muchisimas gracias , una disculpa por no haberlo echo antes GG , solo me quedo la duda de el funcionamieto de el primer codigo , seme hizo interesante el uso de el while pero no comprendi bien ya que siempre e usado sentencias booleanas en su parte de condicional

Comment: @EmmanuelRuiz Si te referís a `for (var i = len-1; i >= 0; i--) {`...`}` .. Ejecuta el mismo código muchas veces modificando la variable `i`, 1 vez por cada elemento, desde el máximo (`len`) hasta el mínimo (`0`). Podrás encontrar más información en https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_en_JavaScript/Control/Bucles

Comment: muchas gracias , he tenido un grave problema que no he podido resolver ala fecha , me gustaría compartir todo mi código  con ustedes , ya que lamentablemente no puedo encontrar el error en micodigo ya que no lo marca y ademas lo e revizado varias veces para encontrar lo que me esta generando el mal comportamiento de una parte de el codigo pero no logro aun encontrarla , muchas gracias por su ayuda hasta el momento , nunca he desistido de mis proyectos pero nunca tube un problema asi , espero poder resolverlo y seguro los contactare por este medio para resolverlo , muchas gracias @Mariano

Answer (score 2):

Una vez que dispones de todos los elementos que deseas eliminar en un NodeList existen numerosas formas de eliminarlos.

La opción más eficiente que se me ocurre en este momento es hacer un bucle [while](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/while) (que normalmente es más rápido que un bucle for) e ir borrando siempre el primer elemento de la lista. No te hace falta ir borrando indices concretos ya que al borrar el primer elemento, el siguiente en la lista pasará a ser el primero y así hasta no existir más elementos.

```
const removeElementsByClass = (container , className) => {
    const elements = container.getElementsByClassName(className);
    while (elements[0]){
        elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Es cierto que en este tipo de operaciones la diferencia de performance es insignificante, pero bajo mi punto de vista es un poco más elegante y más legible. En cualquier caso me parece interesante aportar una solución sin utilizar jQuery.

Comment: Interpreté que el comentario versus el for estaba relacionado a mi respuesta, y no estaba bien. Pensá que para alguien que está empezando, a veces conviene ser explícito en lo que hace un loop. Por cierto, no uso jQuery (lo doy como una segunda alternativa para agregar info)

Comment: Un detalle muy interesante y que sin duda mejora mucho el rendimiento del ejemplo de @Mariano es que calcula el length del NodeList fuera del bucle, de esta manera no se ha de calcular en cada iteración. Otro punto interesante es recorrer el NodeList al revés (i--). Esto en ciertos casos no es posible pero para este caso en concreto es muy acertado.

Comment: P.D. No pretendia descalificar tu respuesta. Me parece muy acertada y como he comentado tiene un par de detalles muy buenos. Tan solo aportar otras opciones. ;)

Comment: eledgaar @Mariano Muchísimas gracias Mariano Por tercera ocasión me has  ayudado y enzenñado y Que detallazo lo se la traducción la verdad que no había comprendido una parte del código que Mariano escribio Muchas gracias (= Algún día  quiero alcanzar su nivel!!